# Is there any way to exclude a single element from the style? (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I have an `img` logo, overlaid on a `div` styled with `background-image: url("...")`, and both elements are inside 2 `div` with classes `.to-color` and `.to-overlay` respectively, to get a black transparent overlay.

Is there any way to exclude the logo from the style given from these 2 classes?

Here's a JSFiddle example: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/qet75juc/)

HTML and CSS from the example:

```
- HTML -

<div class="to-color">
<div class="to-overlay">

 <div class="respo">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 text-center">
    <img src="http://ansonalex.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/google-logo-768x260.png" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
</div>    


- CSS -

.to-color {
 background-color: #000;
}

.to-overlay {
 opacity : 0.5;
}

.respo {
 background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/category/objects/1600x900");
 background-position: center center;
 background-size: cover;
 padding-top: 10%;
 padding-bottom: 20%;
}
```

Comment: You'll have to give the logo a css class, then you'll have to explicitly reset the bg color and opacity from there. css inheritances are a pain...

Comment: Are you allowed to change the markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is making `.to-overlay` and all of its children half-opaque.

Instead of making `.to-overlay` itself half-opaque, use a pseudo-element that will appear *before* the logo and make that half-opaque.

```
.to-color {
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.to-overlay:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Here's the example: https://jsfiddle.net/qet75juc/2/

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I'm quite a newbie, so there are stil several things in CSS that I don't know, and this is definitely one that's gonna be useful in future for sure :D